# Range Selection from last 160 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a filtered table from which I want to copy the last 160 entries. My codes to filter the table works fine but the following codes copy the entire 160 rows. I need the last 160 rows from Column B to S. Also, can I select the last filtered 160 rows (previously filtered with a specific criteria) and not the actual last 160 rows? As per example: last 160 rows may contain row numbers from 90 to 100 with an other criteria.

Thanks for your help. My codes are as follow:

```
Sub FilterRows()

Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long

LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

x = 160

Range(LastRow - x + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy cells B:S of the last 160 visible rows of data.

```
Sub CopyLastXNumberVisibleRows()
    Const MaxRows = 160
    Dim count As Long, lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim SourceRange As Range

    lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

    For x = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Not Rows(x).Hidden And Cells(x,"A") = "Some Criteria" Then
            count = count + 1

            If SourceRange Is Nothing Then
                Set SourceRange = Range(Cells(x, "B"), Cells(x, "S"))
            Else
                Set SourceRange = Union(SourceRange, Range(Cells(x, "B"), Cells(x, "S")))
            End If

            If count = MaxRows Then Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not SourceRange Is Nothing Then

        SourceRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A2")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Robert I updated my answer.  Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I probably do something wrong. I insert the codes as follow but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sub FilterRows()
    Dim rSource As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rSource = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B2:S65536" & Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rSource Is Nothing Then

        rSource.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("AA2")
        
    End If

End Sub

Comment: That was a modified snippet from my previous answer that didn't meet your criteria of coping no more than 160 rows.  My updated should meet all your criteria.

Comment: `Range("B2:S65536" & Rows.count)` is the problem.  Use `Range("B2:S" & Rows.count)` instead.  `Rows.count` will return the correct last row in the worksheet no matter what version on Excel that you use.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I copied the codes entirely but it copies rows 2 to 160 with a specified criteria and not the last 160 entries having the specified criteria. Can you still help me? Thanks again

Comment: Hi Thomas, I meant to say it only copies the rows with a specific criteria between rows 2 to 160.  Unless I did something wrong, it doesn't copy the last 160 rows with a specific criteria. Thank again.

Comment: The confusion comes from it being a filtered table.   I added a criteria clause.  You'll have to adjust it to fit your needs.  Let me know if you need a clarification.

Comment: It works great! I modified the criteria to fit my requirements. Thanks you so much Thomas. I have another question for you. If I want to copy the data on Sheet4 instead of sheet1, it doesn't work. I tried the modify your last line by changing the Sheet number as per the following:         SourceRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet4.Range("A2").

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adjust where you want the output to be copied to,but try this below, Using this part of the code `Cells(1, 1)`

```
Sub test()
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 14).Resize(160, 17).Value = Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, _
                2).End(xlUp).Row - 159, 2).Resize(160, 17).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Sory for been so new in VBA. Should I copy the code and paste it as follow:

Comment: Sub FilterRows()
    Dim rSource As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rSource = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B2:S65536" & Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rSource Is Nothing Then

        rSource.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("AA2")
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(160, 17).Value = Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, _
                2).End(xlUp).Row - 159, 2).Resize(160, 17).Value
    End If

End Sub

Comment: That line will copy all the rows from the last row to 160, you don't need anything else. What is the range you want the data copied to? ie, `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1)`

Comment: HI' I want to copy the last 160 filtered data to Sheet 4, in cell B2.

Comment: Hello KyloRen! My range with data is from Sheet1(B1 to S65536). The titles are on row 1 from B1 to S1. I want to copy the last 160 filtered data  to ("Sheet4").Range ("B2"), The titles are already copied on Sheet4 from B1 to S1. The last 160 filtered data will then be copied to B2 to S161. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can think in another way.Just copy all the filtered data to a new sheet,then use a do while loop to delete extra data.

```
Sub LastRows()
Dim row As Integer

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) 

row = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

If row > 161 Then 'including the title
    Rows("2:" & (row - 160)).Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Please change "Sheet1" to your datasheet's name

Comment: I will try this approach as well, thank you for providing a second option.

Answer (score 0):

you could use such a function:

```
Function FilteredRows(nRowsToCopy As Long, rng As Range, firstCol As String, lastCol As String) As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long: firstRow = 2

    With rng
        With .Offset(1, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=max(R1C:R[-1]C)+1"
            If WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells) > nRowsToCopy Then firstRow = .Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells) - nRowsToCopy + 1, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            .Clear
        End With
        Set FilteredRows = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Parent.Columns(firstCol & ":" & lastCol), .Parent.Rows(firstRow).Resize(.Rows(.Rows.Count).Row - firstRow + 1))
    End With
End Function
```

to be exploited in your main code like follows:

```
FilteredRows(nRowsToCopy, dataRng, "B", "S").Copy
```

where

- `nRowsToCopy` is the (maximum) number of last filtered rows to copy
- `datarng` is the range with all your data (headers included)
- `"B"` and `"S"` are the first and last columns to be copied

Comment: Thank you User 3598756! Your answer is beyond my knowledge! Should I insert the Function codes in a different macro and copy the codes "FilteredRows(nRowToCopy, dataRng, "B", "S").Copy" to my main codes? Do I need to set nRowsToCopy to 160? Do I need to name my table "datarng"? Thanks again

Comment: place `FilteredRows()` in any module. Then in the Sub where you need to get last 160 visible rows range you 1) either define and set a `dataRng` variable of  `Range` type (`Dim dataRng as Range`, `Set dataRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)`) or feed that range directly in the function call (`FilteredRows(nRowsToCopy, ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), "B", "S").Copy`) 2) you can either define and set `nRowsToCopy` (`Dim nRowsToCopy as Long`, `nRowsToCopy=160`) or feed 160

Comment: Thank you again User 3598756!

Comment: Thank you again User 3598756!  I did what you said. I receive a message error on the Line (Run-time error 1004: Application-Defined or Object-Define error) " With .Offset(1, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.count).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.count)". Is it possible a number is missing before the "," = ....Offset(, .Parent.....?

Comment: no. a missing number in Offset method stands for 0. Being the offending line after `With rng` I suspect that you didn't pass a valid `Range` object to `FilteredRows`. Check it. When you meet that error, enter `Debug` and in the Immediate Window type `?rng.Address`, press "Return" and see the result

Comment: @Robert: did you get through it?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for not coming back earlier. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Robert: it'd be nice of you to give feedbacks to people trying helping you